# Add item to Python dictionary while looping over

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dictionary

I have a SPARQL query output which I want to save as a Python dictionary. Where `subject` will be a key and the predicate will be key inside the subject containing respective object. The data look like as follows:

```py
for row in tqdm(qres):
    if 'http' in str(row[0]):
        print(row[0], "|", row[1], "|", row[2])
```

This gives:

```
http://www.orpha.net/ORDO/Orphanet_2514 | http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasExactSynonym | microcephaly (disease), autosomal dominant
http://www.orpha.net/ORDO/Orphanet_2514 | http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasRelatedSynonym | microcephaly, autosomal dominant
http://www.orpha.net/ORDO/Orphanet_2514 | http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasRelatedSynonym | autosomal dominant microcephaly

http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0000722 | http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment | syn of disease free survival
http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0000722 | http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0100001 | http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0004920
http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0000722 | http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000117 | James Malone
http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0000722 | http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label | obsolete_time before disease progression
http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0000722 | http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/reason_for_obsolescence | created as a synonym of progression free survival
```

The target is to have just one URI and all of its predicates associated with it and with predicates its object should be there.

I tried this but failed to see what I am expecting.

```py
ext_feature = {}
for row in (qres):
    if 'http' in str(row[0]):
        ext_feature[str(row[0])]= {str(row[1]):str(row[2])}

for row in tqdm(qres):
    if 'http' in str(row[0]):
        ext_feature[str(row[1])]= str(row[2])
```

This gives the result but leaves some of the information and also not very well formatted outcome which is expected.

```
{'http://www.orpha.net/ORDO/Orphanet_2514': {'http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasDbXref': 'DOID:14725'},
 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0000722': {'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/organizational_class': 'true'},
 'http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasExactSynonym': 'autosomal dominant primary microcephaly',
 'http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasRelatedSynonym': 'microcephaly with autosomal dominant inheritance',
 'http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasDbXref': 'DOID:14725',
 'http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000115': 'Autosomal dominant form of microcephaly (disease).',
 'http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#id': 'Orphanet:2514',
 'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label': 'obsolete_time before disease progression',
 'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment': 'candidate for deprecation',
 'http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0100001': 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0004920',
 'http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000117': 'James Malone',
 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/reason_for_obsolescence': 'created as a synonym of progression free survival',
 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/organizational_class': 'true'}
```

Expected output:

```
{'http://www.orpha.net/ORDO/Orphanet_2514':{'http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasExactSynonym':'microcephaly (disease), autosomal dominant', 'http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasRelatedSynonym':'microcephaly, autosomal dominant', 'http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasRelatedSynonym': 'autosomal dominant microcephaly'}
```

Similar result is expected for the other URIs. I saw many answers related to dictionary but couldn't follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

ext_feature = defaultdict(lambda: dict())

for col1, col2, col3 in qres:
    if 'http' in str(col1):
      ext_feature[str(col1)].update({str(col2): str(col3)})

print(dict(ext_feature))
```

Note - I am not sure why you cast with str(), as it is looking like it is already list of strings. I left the casting just in case.

Answer (score 0):

```python
In [1]: f = [["http://www.orpha.net/ORDO/Orphanet_2514", "http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasExactSynonym", "microcephaly (disease), autosomal dominant"],
   ...: ["http://www.orpha.net/ORDO/Orphanet_2514", "http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasRelatedSynonym", "microcephaly, autosomal dominant"],
   ...: ["http://www.orpha.net/ORDO/Orphanet_2514", "http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasRelatedSynonym", "autosomal dominant microcephaly"],
   ...: ["http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0000722", "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment", "syn of disease free survival"],
   ...: ["http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0000722", "http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0100001",  "http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0004920"],
   ...: ["http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0000722", "http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000117",  "James Malone"],
   ...: ["http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0000722", "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label",  "obsolete_time before disease progression"],
   ...: ["http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0000722", "http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/reason_for_obsolescence", "created as a synonym of progression free survival"]]

In [2]: d = {}
   ...: for row in f:
   ...:     if not row[0] in d:
   ...:         d[row[0]] = dict()
   ...:     d[row[0]][row[1]] = row[2]
   ...: 

In [3]: d
Out[3]: 
{'http://www.orpha.net/ORDO/Orphanet_2514': {'http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasExactSynonym': 'microcephaly (disease), autosomal dominant',
  'http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasRelatedSynonym': 'autosomal dominant microcephaly'},
 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0000722': {'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment': 'syn of disease free survival',
  'http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0100001': 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/EFO_0004920',
  'http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000117': 'James Malone',
  'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label': 'obsolete_time before disease progression',
  'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/reason_for_obsolescence': 'created as a synonym of progression free survival'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

We go through the list, check if there is a key in the dict, if there is no such key, then create it, then check it again for the presence of a key, if not, then create it. See the result

```
input_data = [
            [
                'http://www.orpha.net/ORDO/Orphanet_2514',
                'http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasExactSynonym',
                'microcephaly (disease), autosomal dominant'
            ],
            [
                'http://www.orpha.net/ORDO/Orphanet_2514',
                'http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasRelatedSynonym',
                ' microcephaly, autosomal dominant'
            ],
            [
                'http://www.orpha.net/ORDO/Orphanet_2514',
                'http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasRelatedSynonym',
                'autosomal dominant microcephaly'
            ]
        ]
    
      
    dict_res = {}
    for item in input_data:
        if not item[0] in dict_res:
            dict_res[item[0]] = {}
        if not item[1] in dict_res[item[0]]:
            dict_res[item[0]][item[1]] = ''
     
        dict_res[item[0]][item[1]] +=item[2] + ' '
    print(dict_res)
```